# Help with 2nd Order Coupled ODEs

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, computational-physics, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a 2nd Order Coupled ODE for A "Looping Pendulum" numerically with MATLAB. Can anyone please recommend how? (which ODE solver to use) Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Try ode45. You need to rewrite this as a first order system and define the proper function in input to it. Anyhow, check the help.

Comment: To solve ODE with Matlab you must transfer the equations in first order equations

Comment: You may try the free version of WolframAlpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/ or the more powerful Mathematica?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about writing code in a specific language for OP and not about physics.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image]
Matlab simulation for your example. Integration methode RK4. 
I forgot to put the simulation time
t=linspace(0,10,300) simulation for 10 sec with 300 points

Comment: Wait...you took the time to *write* the code by hand & posting a screenshot of it instead of *typing* it in?

Comment: well i don’t have Latex in my Ipad

Comment: You don't need latex for two reasons: 1) this site is enabled with MathJax (latex equivalent) and 2) this site is enabled with code formatting so you can manually type in the code...

Comment: That said, I don't think you should give OP your work. They cannot learn how to do something as trivial as solving an ODE numerically if people just give them the answer.